# symfony autocompletion in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, symfony1

im using netbeans to code a web application with symfony.

it seems that netbeans doesnt support symfony in auto completion.

could one fix this problem.

cause i want to be able to click on symfony's functions and get to the source, eg helper function and model methods and classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the path to symfony classes to the include path under your project.

Comment: Or actually put the full source in your project. Personally i like to do it this way with an svn:external pegged to a tagged release. Generally every project i do gets deployed to its own server so it doesnt make sense not to embed symfony within the project anyway.